# How to always have 2 decimal places on a Double

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that goes through a list of text, extracts the dollar amounts, increase them by 12%, and replaces the text with the updated dollar amounts.

This what a couple rows of data looks like:
[image]

This is the result after I run the macro:
[image]

I would need the `72.8` to be `72.80` tho, for example.

Sometimes the result would just have 1 decimal place and sometimes it would have 3. The `Round` function works fine for me with truncating the result down to 2 decimal places, but doesn't help adding a 0 to keep the number at two decimal places.

I need a way to have fill the second decimal place with a 0 if the result only has 1 decimal place.

This is the macro:

```
Function onlyDigits(s As String) As String
' Variables needed (remember to use "option explicit").   '
Dim retval As String    ' This is the return string.      '
Dim i As Integer        ' Counter for character position. '

' Initialise return string to empty                       '
retval = ""

' For every character in input string, copy digits to     '
'   return string.                                        '
For i = 1 To Len(s)
    If Mid(s, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(s, i, 1) <= "9" Then
        retval = retval + Mid(s, i, 1)
    End If
Next

' Then return the return string.                          '
onlyDigits = retval
End Function

Sub ChangeDollarAmount()

Dim qtyspec As String
Dim previousDollarIndex As Integer
Dim dollarSignCount As Integer
Dim dollarString As String
Dim originalDollarAmount As String
Dim changedDollarAmount As Double
Dim isANumber As Boolean

previousDollarIndex = 1

' row count
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

For Each cell In Range("K2:K" & lastrow)
    Debug.Print cell.Formula

    previousDollarIndex = 1
    qtyspec = cell.Formula
    dollarSignCount = (Len(cell.Formula) - Len(Replace(cell.Formula, "$", ""))) / Len("$")

    ' loop through dollar amounts in text
    For i = 1 To dollarSignCount
        isANumber = False
        previousDollarIndex = InStr(previousDollarIndex + 1, cell.Formula, "$")
        originalDollarAmount = Mid(cell.Formula, previousDollarIndex, 8)

        Do While isANumber = False
            If Not IsNumeric(Right(originalDollarAmount, 1)) Then
                originalDollarAmount = Left(originalDollarAmount, Len(originalDollarAmount) - 1)
            Else
                isANumber = True
            End If
        Loop

        ' extract only digits from dollar amount ($345.23 -> 34523)
        dollarAmount = onlyDigits(originalDollarAmount)

        ' add decimal point and increase dollar amount by 12% (34523 -> 345.23 -> 386.66)
        changedDollarAmount = Round(CDbl(dollarAmount) * 1.12 * 0.01, 2)

        ' update the dollar amount in the text
        cell.Formula = Replace(cell.Formula, originalDollarAmount, "$" + CStr(changedDollarAmount))
    Next i

Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: If this is so that the number appears correctly in Excel, format the cell (or cells in the column) to display two decimal places.

Comment: Unrelated, but note that [`Round`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/round-function) uses bankers rounding. You may want the worksheet function.

Comment: The cell has numbers and symbols that aren't dollars, so I'm extracting the dollars amounts specifically and modifying those. So a cell's contents would look like: `[(250, '250 - $28'), (500, '500 - $33.60'), (1000, '1000 - $44.80')]`

Comment: So it's all text then... and now I've no idea what you're trying to do. Perhaps include more of your code in the question itself along with some sample data?

Comment: Updated the question, hopefully its much clearer now

Answer (score 1):

```
changedDollarAmount = CDbl(dollarAmount) * 1.12 * 0.01

cell.Formula = Replace(cell.Formula, originalDollarAmount, Format$(changedDollarAmount, "$0.00"))
```